# Cassandra data synchronization and full repair

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, cassandra-2.2

I'm running a Cassandra 2.2.8 cluster of 3 nodes in a single data center. The replication factor is 3.

I had to recover one of the nodes from an old backup. After recovering the backup I ran a full repair to sync the latest data, but it seems that the recovered node has less data than the others:

[image]

How can I force data synchronization?

Comment: have you run a `nodetool cleanup` after topology changes + repairs?

Answer (score 0):

One idea might be checking the system.log when doing full repair. is there any error over there about repair? if so, debug the errors and fix them.

Otherwise, one pre-check is to run nodetool [verify](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsVerify.html) on the recovered node to see whether there're any corrupt sstable even after repair?

If nothing is wrong, there're a lot of possibilities and it's hard to debug  without more knowledge on your cluster. Cassandra also doesn't have a direct idea about whether all data are consistent.

maybe if you know the number of object you already put, you can run [cqlsh](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/cqlsh.html) command to count all data tables to see whether they're a match to see whether you really loose any data?